# Import type and value in the same line for isolatedModules=true?

Tags: typescript

Typescript has type-only imports

```
import type { Foo } from "./types"
```

If the same file also exports values we could add a second import statement:

```
import type { Foo } from "./types";
import { BarValue } from "./types"
```

Is it possible to import a type and a value in the same statement?

Comment: I think isn't possible in typescript. You would need separate import statements for types and values.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to use the `import type` syntax if your bundler needs it. From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#typescript-specific-es-module-syntax):

> ...these allow a non-TypeScript transpiler like Babel, swc or esbuild to know what imports can be safely removed.

So unless you need that, you can just use `import`:

```
import { Foo, BarValue } from "./types";
```

If you *do* need that, then as of v4.5, [you can use the `type` prefix on individual parts of the `import`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#inline-type-imports):

```
import { type Foo, BarValue } from "./types";
```

FWIW, I use plain `import` statements that import types along with values all the time, including in projects using `isolatedModules: true` in the `tsconfig.json`. The bundlers I use (primarily [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), but also Webpack) don't need the `import type` syntax.

Just to be sure, I just double-checked it in a completely fresh project:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": true
    }
}
```

`types.ts`

```typescript
export type Foo = {
    a: number;
};

export const BarValue = 42;
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { Foo, BarValue } from "./types";

const a: Foo = {
    a: 42,
};
console.log(BarValue);
console.log(a);
```

`tsc` ran just fine and produced the `types.js` and `main.js` files as expected. I double-checked it's happy to output either ESM or CommonJS with that `import` (naturally, the type part of it is omitted).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in newest version of ts:

```
import { type Foo, BarValue } from "./types";
```

Comment: Yeah, that was [added in v4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#inline-type-imports). I had *just* updated my answer to mention it. :-)

Comment: fair enough, you get an upvote from me